# scanf single char not working with my loops

Tags: c

So I've been working on a code for a 2d treasure hunt where I use single char's from a scanf and whether it is n,s,w,e it does a specific output.  Unfortunately my code is not listening to my input, for example, when I type in n, nothing happens.  I was wondering if you guys could point me onto the right path

```
do
{
    printf("Please press n, s, w, or e to find the treasure\n");
    scanf(" %c", &n);
    if (scanf(" %c", &n) == 'n')
    {
        current - 11;
        new = current - 11;
        if (abs(potofgold - current) < abs(potofgold - new))
            printf("getting warmer\n");
        else if (abs(potofgold - current) > abs(potofgold - new))
            printf("Getting colder\n");
        else
            printf("Hooray\n");
        current = new;
    }
    else if (scanf("%c", &s) == 's')
    {
        current + 11;
        new = current + 11;
        if (abs(potofgold - current) < abs(potofgold - new))
            printf("Getting warmer\n");
        else if (abs(potofgold - current) > abs(potofgold - new))
            printf("getting colder\n");
        else
            printf("Hooray\n");
        current = new;
    }
    else if (scanf("%c", e) == 'e')
    {
        current + 1;
        new = current + 1;
        if (abs(potofgold - current) < abs(potofgold - new))
            printf("getting warmer\n");
        else if (abs(potofgold - current) > abs(potofgold - new))
            printf("getting colder\n");
        else
            printf("Hooray\n");
        current = new;
    }
    else (scanf("%c", &w) == 'w');
    {
        current - 1;
        new = current - 1;
        if (abs(potofgold - current) < abs(potofgold - new))
            printf("getting warmer\n");
        else if (abs(potofgold - current) > abs(potofgold - new))
            printf("getting colder\n");
        else
            printf("Hooray\n");

        current = new;
    }
}
while (current != potofgold);

return 0;
```

Comment: You seem to be missing an `if` on your last `scanf("%c", &w) == 'w'`.

Comment: you ask a question about a runtime problem, but did not post a minimal code that cleanly compiles that shows the problem.   Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: for clarity/readability of the code, strongly suggest the actions that follow a 'n' or 's' or 'w' or 'e' be placed in small sub functions.   Then it will be obvious that scanf() is being called way too many times for one user input.  Strongly suggest: only one call to scanf() then perform all the tests on the resulting variable value (which may suggest using a switch statement on the resulting variable with the possible values being the 'case' statements

Comment: maybe, with statements like: `       current - 11;` what you actually meant was: `       current -= 11;`   note the proper operator to change the value of `current`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take input first `scanf("%c", &variable)` above the `if` condition.
Use `if (n == 'n')` instead of `if (scanf(" %c", &n) == 'n')` for each if condition. Because `scanf` return the number of input, it can take successfully

Answer (score 2):

These conditions won't be true in any case-

```
if (scanf(" %c", &n) == 'n')       // compare variable with character n=='n' 
....
else if (scanf("%c", &s) == 's')              // s=='s'
....
else if (scanf("%c", e) == 'e')               // e=='e'
                    ^ & missing here
```

`scanf` here in each case return `1` on success . Don't compare it with characters.

Instead you can write conditions like this -

```
 if (scanf(" %c", &n) == 1 && n=='n')     // if scanf will be successful then only n=='n' will be evaluated. Thus , on failure of scanf scond condition will not be evaluated
  ....
 else if (scanf("%c", &s) ==1 && s=='s')  
 ....
 else if (scanf("%c", &e) == 1 && e=='e')
```

And this should be `else if`-

```
 else (scanf("%c", &w) == 'w');   // else ends here (It should be else if)
{                                      // this is after else part 
    current - 1;           // remove this , compiler will issue an error\warning
    new = current - 1;     
    if (abs(potofgold - current) < abs(potofgold - new))
        printf("getting warmer\n");
    else if (abs(potofgold - current) > abs(potofgold - new))
        printf("getting colder\n");
    else
        printf("Hooray\n");

    current = new;
}
```

And these

```
 current - 11;  // do you mean current-=11;
 current + 11;  // as current+=11;
 current +1 ;   // as current +=1;
 current -1 ;   // as current -=1;
```

Comment: this line: `    current - 1;` will cause the compiler to raise a warning/error message.  Suggest removing this line

Comment: @user3629249  Yes , I will mention it .

Comment: `new` is a reserved word in any compiler that can compile C++ code.  suggest using a more expressive name, like: `newCurrent`

Comment: Question is tagged C and `new` is a perfectly valid variable name.

Comment: @AlterMann Just a suggestion rather unnecessary .

Comment: IMHO is not a good suggestion, I use `new` precisely to avoid C++ compilers.

Comment: @AlterMann  Yes , I removed it .

Comment: @AlterMann  Thank You !! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems, even in a fragment this small:

```
do
{
    printf("Please press n, s, w, or e to find the treasure\n");
    scanf(" %c", &n);
    if (scanf(" %c", &n) == 'n')
    {
```

It is good that you are using `" %c"` to read the characters.

First, you don't check whether the first `scanf()` succeeded.  It is going to return one of 3 values in theory (2 in practice).  Those values could be `EOF` if it detects end-of-file on standard input, `1` if it reads a non-blank character (possibly after multiple newlines and blanks and tabs), and in general it could return `0` if it fails to read input that satisfies the conversion specification without encountering EOF or an error.  With a numeric conversion specification (such as `%d`), that could happen if the first non-blank character was a letter; when the conversion specification is simply reading a character (`%c`), you won't get `0` returned.

Then, in the `if` statement, you read another character.  But, since `scanf()` only returns `EOF` or `1`, it is not going to equal `'n'`, so the `if` will fail, and will move onto the `else` where you read another character, and so on.